# How to get all translations message domains in Symfony

Tags: symfony, translation

TL;DR: I would like to programmatically get all [Message Translations Domains](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/translation.html#using-message-domains) of an application made with Symfony 3.4.

An example of expected result:

```
$domains = $this->get('translator')->getDomains();
//$domains = ['home', 'messages', ...]
```

But i don't find a method returning application domains in translator service.
Is there an another service returning all application domains?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Ok i found the solution:

```
$this->getContainer()->get('translator')->getCatalogue()->getDomains();
```

This solution works for bundles if you store their translations as Symfony 3.4 recommend it : in `bundles/Resources/translations/` folder. 
Otherwise you should precise the path in in config.yml:

```
framework:
    translator:
        ...
        paths:
            - '%kernel.project_dir%/xxx/translations'
```

Comment: It can be useful indeed. Thanks.